# Chance of getting six in three dice

Tags: probability, dice

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this and am sure that my answers are wrong.

There are three dice.

A. Chance of getting exactly one six on the three dice.
$$(1/6) * 3 = 1/3$$

B. Chance of getting exactly two sixes.
$$(1/6 * 1/6) * 1.5 = 1/24$$

C. Chance of getting exactly $~3~$ sixes.
$$1/6 * 1/6 * 1/6 = 1/216$$

D. Chance of any combination of A, B and C
$$1/3 + 1/24 + 1/216=
72/216 + 9/216 + 1/216 = 82/216$$

Comment: The chance of getting a six on any of the three dice would be $\frac{1}{6}\times 6=1$ if $6$ dice were thrown. Certainty. Doesn't that make you suspicuous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A. There is a total of 6^3=216 combinations if you roll 3 dice. There are 5^2x3=75 combinations that you will get one 6. Thus there is a 75/216=**25/72** chance of getting only one 6 when rolling 3 dice.

B. There are 5x3 combinations that you will get 2 6s. Thus there is a 15/216=**5/72** chance of getting a 2 6s when rolling 3 dice.

C. There is 1 combination where you will get 3 6s. Thus there is a **1/216** chance you will get 3 6s when rolling 3 dice. (Good job you got this correct)

D. There is a 75+15+1/216=**91/216** chance of any of them happening.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thx I always get the 2 mixed up :)

Comment: Where this number came from (5^2)*3?

Comment: Seems like if you don't care about order, rolling a six once would give you 25 possibilities, not 75.

Comment: @Misaki I figured it out. There are three "cases" where there is exactly one six on three dice: `6,x,x` / `x,6,x` / `x,x,6`. The `x` stands for anything but 6, so a number in [1, 5] (5 different sides).

When dice #1 is 6 (the first case), there are 5*5 = 5^2 = 25 (the two `x`) combinations where dice #2 and #3 are anything but 6.

The same is true for the other two cases, and thus: 5^2 + 5^2 + 5^2 = (5^2)*3.

Answer (score 3):

Hint for A: what is the chance that no sixes appear? If you know that chance then you automatically know the chance that sixes ***do*** appear.

Answer (score 3):

The chance of getting *at least one* 6 with three dice is 91/216 because if you subtract 125/216 (the probability of rolling three dice without getting a 6) from 216/216 (the probability of any combination of numbers), you get 91/216.

Comment: Yes!  I earned my first up vote!